# Radio buttons to enable/disable fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a form with several groups of radio buttons. Selecting a radio button will enable the `text` field against it and disable the rest.
I cant get the field enabled. I have already tried almost every function (next, nextAll, nextUnit, find, findAll, closest ...) but probably not using them properly.

Here is a test with only one group of buttons: http://jsfiddle.net/QTseK/

Also on page load some of the radio buttons are already checked and what I have to run to get the rest (not checked fields) disabled ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your elements have class attributes, you can select them using class selector, for enabling/disabling form elements, you can use the `prop` method.

```
$("body").on("click", "input[type='radio']", function() {
    $('.fieldSelector').prop('disabled', true);
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.fieldSelector').prop('disabled', false)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AfRdj/

Comment: Also `$("input[type^='radio']").not(':checked').each` for disabling the fields on startup. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheJoeFletch/QTseK/1/)

```
$("body").on("click", "input[type=radio]", function() {
   $(this).closest("table").find("input[type=text]").prop("disabled", true);
    $(this).closest("tr").find("input[type=text]").prop("disabled", false);

});​
```

You can add/modify the selectors based on your HTML.

In addition, I am not sure that I would put the event listener on the body. I think that I would prefer something like this if the elements are in the DOM throughout the page life cycle. (Are the elements in question on the page initially?)

```
$("input[type=radio]").on("click", function() {//you can change input[type=radio] to any other selector that you have already used
   $(this).closest("table").find("input[type=text]").prop("disabled", true);
    $(this).closest("tr").find("input[type=text]").prop("disabled", false);

});​
```